# Get location updates using location callbacks

Tags: java, android, location-services, google-location-services, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm trying to get the user location using `FusedLocationProviderClient` as follows:

```
fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, locationCallback, null);
```

I get location updates in this location calls

```
 locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult); 
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    // list of locations
                }
            }
        };
```

I read that `locationResult.getLocations()` retrieves a list of location objects ordered from oldest to newest,
I couldn't understand that all I want is to get the user location at the moment.

Any help regarding this?

Comment: in lace of loop of locations, you must use **locationResult.getLastLocation()** This will help you

Comment: or go to the official documention for further help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `locationResult.getLastLocation()` to get the most up to date location available.

From the docs: [LocationResult.getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationResult.html#getLastLocation())

```
public Location getLastLocation ()
    Returns the most recent location 
    available in this result, or null if no 
    locations are available.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LocationManager` instead of `FusedLocationProviderClient`. It could be more easier.

```
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("Current location", location.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };
    //Checks permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

This will give you location when user moves.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it takes more time getting the user location using LocationListener